# Use 'noty' js library in Rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, npm

I am trying to make noty.js ( https://ned.im/noty/#/installation
 - a library for notifications) work into my Rails app.

I have installed it with npm

```
 npm install noty
```

Now, it appears under `node_modules`.
When I try to test it in a js file with

```
new Noty({

    text: 'Some notification text'

}).show();
```

I will get `' Uncaught ReferenceError: Noty is not defined'` 
If I try to import it in my js file : import Noty from 'noty' ;   I will get `'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier'` ( my 'noty' path is visible- I can be directed to it).

How can I properly make it work?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: @DanielWestendorf  No .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using webpack or some other JS asset management system, installing with NPM won't work. You'll need to

1. Download `noty.css` and `noty.js`, place them in their respective assets directory
2. Add them to your `assets.rb`
3. Restart your server
4. Reference the file in your layout prior to your `application.js`

Read the guides on the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline) for more details.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "noty" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "noty" %>
```