# How to correctly use use Noty in ruby or rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, noty

I'm new at Ruby on Rails and I was attempting to implement notifications using [Noty](https://ned.im/noty/#/installation?id=install-via-yarn) but fails.

Installation procedure:

Stopped localhost server

```
$ yarn add noty
```

```
# app/javascript/packs/application.js
...
window.Noty = require("noty")
```

Below I'm unable to import noty

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
...
@import "noty/lib/noty.js"; # not working
@import "noty/lib/noty";    # not working either
```

I can confirm the library is stated in the package.json and yarn.lock

I have also seen [this possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643755/use-noty-js-library-in-rails-5), and in my assets.rb, node_modules is already referenced...

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
```

... and the files noty.css and noty.js already exist in node_modeles/noty/lib

Answer (score 0):

I solved this simply by downloading the files at [noty Github](https://github.com/needim/noty/tree/master/lib) and place them in the correct directory.

Comment: Another great solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117571/how-to-import-node-modules-with-webpacker)